# Expression describing code written by inexperienced, lazy and untalented developers

Tags: expressions, terminology, pejorative-language, programming

One of my characters is a young graduate student who leaves her adviser. He takes her research code and he gets his other students to use it, not forgetting to say all sorts of mean things about her and the code.

I need a derogatory expression for code that is written by a young and inexperienced developer who contains many typical mistakes: do loops that do nothing, non-descriptive names for variables, monolithic blocks, repeated blocks of code where a function will do, inconsistent naming convention, etc.

I have heard terms like "spaghetti code", "hydra code", "jenga code", but they don't necessary imply ineptitude on the part of the developer. Also I've heard the term "Jimmy" describing the clueless developer. "Jimmy code" would be a choice then, but I'm not a programmer, so I don't know what is used.

Comment: So this so called advisor takes this garbage code and makes all the other students use it?  Why would he do that?

Comment: @Jim The code is actually working, but he claims it's garbage. That's how he rolls.

Comment: My fellow developers call this type of code "hacky code".

Comment: @RobJarvis "Sloppy, hacky code" sounds good.

Comment: "Ordinary Python code" maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I think "spaghetti code" implies ineptitude, but it might also implies several developers and something that grew out of control over time. "Legacy code" is another excuse I hear for crap code. When a developer is speaking of their own garbage code they call it "quick and dirty" implying they just didn't have time to do a good job. "Hack" is often misunderstood to mean "crack" security, but it really means inelegant, inefficient code that works.

FWIW, some people don't like compact, elegant code if it ends up hard to read and understand. slightly longer, but readable code is sometimes preferred.

Comment: Legacy code is what half of professional programmers get to work with. It can be good or bad, like any other code. But there is a special place in hell reserved for those who don’t comment it.

Comment: To me, Spaghetti code has always meant code that uses lots of gotos so that the thread of execution jumps and loops around much like a strand of spaghetti in a pile.

Comment: Yes, "spaghetti code" implies a particular type of fault, lack of structure.